# Solr - boost multivalued field based on number of matches

Tags: solr, lucene, solrj

Our Solr version is 7.6. I've the following doc schema:

```
  <field name="name" type="text_en" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
  <field name="reviewCount" type="pint" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

And this is the kind of query running in the application:

```
{!boost b=log(sum(1,reviewCount))}(name:dell AND id:(48 OR 178 OR 284))
```

I'm looking for a way to boost docs that have more matches in `id` field - doc with `id (48,178,284)` (among other possible values) should be higher in the response than doc with `id (48,284)`, which in turn should be higher comparing to docs with `id (48)` or `id (178)` or `id (284)`. Is that possible?

Comment: Appending `debug=all` should give you detailed information about what each field contributes to the score

Comment: How that helps to boost docs according to number of matches in the multiValued field?

Comment: Because that will tell you what the score contributed from the `id` field now is - and if there's any difference between the two already. Usually matching on more terms will give a higher score, but it will depend on which query parser you're using and how the scoring happens. Appending `debug=all` will give you detailed information about how the score for your document is being calculated, allowing you to find out exactly what's happening now (for example, edismax uses the maximum score from disjunct queries which is different from the default lucene query parser).

Comment: So once I'll find that, is there boosting function that boosts docs that have more matches in the multiValued field?

Comment: The default behavior is that the more terms that results in a hit, the higher the score is. Whether the field is mulitvalued or not doesn't really matter.